# How to get error number in $? and the o/p in response

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

I am trying to connect to a host and run the netstat command,using the below:

```
NET_STAT=$(ssh $hostname netstat -an 2>&1)

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
echo “error occurred”
```

1. When SSH is successful i should have netstat o/p in NET_STAT.
2. When SSH fails I should have Error written into NET_STAT.(because i added 2>&1)

So to check if the command succeeded I use “$?”.
But the problem is whether the command fails or succeeds $? is always 0. I think this is because the second part of the command(2>&1) always succeeds and so I get 0.

Is there a way that I get the return code as non-zero so that I can distinguish success and failure. And also get the proper o/p in NET_STAT.

Here is an example:

hostname=1.2.3.4

NET_STAT=$(ssh $hostname netstat -an 2>&1)

echo "val of err is $NET_STAT"

echo "val of ret val is $?"

output

=========

val of err is ssh: 1.2.3.4: node name or 
service name not known

val of ret val is 0

Comment: From the shell spec (section 2.9.1at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html):  "If there is no command name, but the command contained a command substitution, the command shall complete with the exit status of the last command substitution performed."  Your understanding is basically correct: something else is happening.  Perhaps you execute another command that you haven't shown here.  How do you know ssh is failing in your test case?

Comment: `2>&1` is *not* succeeding and overriding the exit status if `2>&1` failed your command would never even have been run. WilliamPursell is likely correct, either `ssh` is *not* failing or some other command is being run between that `ssh` line and the `if` test.

Comment: How or why does the SSH command fail?

Comment: "whether the command fails or succeeds $? is always 0". What are you considering to be a command failure? Could you provide an example of a case where the command failed and the exit code was 0?

Comment: I am considering SSH to be a command. i have updated the main question with an example, where SSH fails for 1.2.3.4

Comment: The ‘$?‘ in your example is probably 0 because of the ‘echo‘ command that preceded it.

Comment: Why not just check the content of $NET_STAT for something recognisable. ie:

Comment: I am giving a bad ip address purposely so that my SSH command fails.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check $NET_STAT for something that confirms that the netstat command has worked:

```
if echo $NET_STAT | grep "^Active" > /dev/null
then
    echo "All ok"
else
    echo "not ok"
fi
```